# Excel VBA Setting up an Error Box if value doesn't exist after looking for a value in a row based cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set up a macro that imports data from another sheet and then places it in the current tab. The order of this data is sometimes different so I've set up a search function that looks for a specific value based on a cell value. Then selects that column of data and places where it should be. This is what I've been using.

```
Sub SelectData ()
'For Selecting Depth Column Data on Meter Data Tab During Import Meter Data
Dim x As String
x = Cells(9, 14)
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lColumn = 150 'colums from A to check during delete
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(25, iCntr) = x Then 'You can change this text
        Cells(24, iCntr).Select
    End If
Next
'For selecting the whole data
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(105000, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)).Select
'Paste the data in the apropriate column
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Now today I though of adding an `ElseIf`for a situation where the value in the cell that is being used to selected the pasted data doesn't exist in the data. Which would prompt a message box saying that there is no such value. When I add the `Elseif` it is now always putting the Error Box.

```
Sub SelectData ()
'For Selecting Depth Column Data on Meter Data Tab During Import Meter Data
Dim x As String
x = Cells(9, 14)
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lColumn = 150 'colums from A to check during delete
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(25, iCntr) = x Then 'You can change this text
        Cells(24, iCntr).Select
    ElseIf Cells(25, iCntr) <> x Then 'You can change this text
        MsgBox "Your value in cell N8 does not match the value in Row 2 inside the Meter Data Spreadsheet. Make sure they match and try again." & vbNewLine & "No Data for DEPTH was Imported."
        Exit Sub        
    End If
Next
'For selecting the whole data
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(105000, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)).Select
'Paste the data in the apropriate column
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you loop backwards? Think the problem is that as soon as a cell doesn't match you get the message and it exits the sub whereas you need it check the whole range first. Using your loop, you could use a Boolean flag. But the Find method would be better.

Comment: @SJR What do you mean by I'm doing the loop backwards?

Comment: Step -1. Nothing wrong with it, just wondered why.

Comment: @SJR Oh I didn't even notice it. Some 2 or 3 years ago there must have been a method to my madness. So I've looked into the Find method. Played around with it and got this `Dim x As String
On Error GoTo Oops
x = Cells(9, 14)
Set cell = Range("G24:O500000").Find(What:=x)
cell.Select
Exit Sub
Oops: msgbox "Ooops "
Range("A1").Select` Does this makse sense? Seems way simpler than my backwards loop :D. I with I knew this existed long ago. Never managed to stumble on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have solved it already, but here is an example of the Find method. You should also avoid the Selects and ActiveCells. You might have to specify some of the Find parameters (advisable).

```
Sub SelectData()

Dim x As String
x = Cells(9, 14)
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim r As Range

lColumn = 150
Set r = Range(Cells(25, 1), Cells(25, lColumn)).Find(x)

If r Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Your value in cell N8 does not match the value in Row 2 inside the Meter Data Spreadsheet. Make sure they match and try again." & vbNewLine & "No Data for DEPTH was Imported."
    Exit Sub
Else
    r.Offset(-1).Resize(105000).Copy
    Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```